# Binding click event in jquery coffeescript

Tags: jquery-mobile, coffeescript

I am working on rails 3.2 and using coffeescript too..
I have a doubt in using jquery mobile inside my application
I have a html like

```
<a href="#" data-item=12 data-status=true class="follow">
  <span class="ui-btn-inner">
    <span class="ui-btn-text">
      Follow
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

In my coffeescript, i am trying to write function on click of this Follow, i am trying to send a ajax call.

when i wrote like

```
  $("a.follow").unbind('click').bind 'click', (event, data) ->
      event.stopPropagation()
      clickedEl = $(event.target)
      console.log(clickedEl)
```

Console.log prints span with class "ui-btn-text" at times and span with "ui-btn-inner" at times.

But in my coffeescript function , i need to actually take attributes from a tag. How to proceed with this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) instead of `event.target`:

> The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gdzUC/

Or [`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/):

> The element where the currently-called jQuery event handler was attached.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/UhBWM/

You could also use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
clickedEl = $(this).closest('a')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2LHp3/

The [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) value is:

> The DOM element that initiated the event.

In other words, it is the thing that was actually clicked on. The `currentTarget` and `delegateTarget` will be the thing that the event is bound to. Using `closest` is probably overkill for this, you'd usually use that to go up the DOM to an container that holds several items that you're interacting with.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to always get the link element, you then have a reference to work from if you need info from the contained spans.

```
...
  clickedEl = $(event.target)
  parentLink = clickedEl.parentsUntil $("a.follow")
  console.log(parentLink)
```

Comment: ah, you are right, parentsUntil does not include the matched element. closest is the right function to use.