# Trouble with JQuery .is() in toggle interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have this slider interaction where I want to collapse or expand the div anywhere UNLESS they click a link within that big div, then I just want the link to work without any collapsing/uncollapsing. Problem is, .is() (see what I did there?).

I'm using jquery.

Here's the code (sorry that it's in coffeescript, but I was too lazy to reverse translate):

```
$ ->
  # SLIDER INTERACTION
  $(".page-content").click (e) ->
    # This first part is just because ie only recognizes srcElement, not target
    if e.target
      $targ = e.target
    else $targ = e.srcElement  if e.srcElement

    # Now I check to see if they clicked a link, if so, follow the link
    if $targ.is("a")
      true

    # If they clicked a collapsed profile, expand it
    else if $(this).hasClass(".collapsed")
      $(this).css "margin-bottom": "0px"
      $(this).removeClass ".collapsed"
      $(this).find(".review-btns, .section-header, .dl-horizontal").show()

    # Otherwise, collapse it
    else
      $(this).css "margin-bottom": "20px"
      $(this).addClass ".collapsed"
      $(this).find(".review-btns, .section-header, .dl-horizontal").hide()
```

Now that seems solid to me, but when I click on anything I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'is'
```

I've been bashing my head against the table. It's probably something stupid, I'm beyond my depth here.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know coffeescript, but it's clear that your error stems from the fact that `$targ` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object (and thus doesn't have the [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method). I believe to fix it you just have to wrap it:

```
if e.target
  $targ = $(e.target)
else $targ = $(e.srcElement)  if e.srcElement
```

(I believe this is the right way, seeing [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10613787/520779) in this site, but if it's not I'm afraid I can't help you...)

Comment: See, I knew it would be dumb. Thanks mgibsonbr

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$targ = e.target` use `$targ = $(e.target)`

Or you can update the if condition as

```
if $($targ).is("a")
      true
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance looks like you didn't get the target as a jQuery object, with its methods.

Try changing

```
if e.target
  $targ = e.target
else $targ = e.srcElement  if e.srcElement
```

to

```
if e.target
  $targ = $(e.target)
else $targ = $(e.srcElement)  if e.srcElement
```

which should set $targ to an actual jquery object of the referenced node.